# How to write to LOGBOOK drawer in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I like to have the creation time of my tasks in `org-mode`.  To that end, I used [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52815573/466228) to setup a hook to add the create time to a new entry. It's working pretty well but I find I'd actually like to log this in the `LOGBOOK` drawer instead.

[This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35776/8240) (which was actually referenced by the first answer) shows how to insert the `CREATED` property into the `PROPERTIES` drawer but for the life of me I can't find how I would modify that to insert into the `LOGBOOK` drawer instead.

As a follow-up, if someone can tell me where I could have found this that would be awesome.  I looked all through the `org-mode` docs but couldn't really find a complete reference.  The [worg site](https://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html) has a great reference for hooks and though it says it includes commands, I'm not sure it does (e.g., `org-entry-put`).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that I can think of **but which only works** for TODO's from capture templates is to use the following capture template

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  '(("t" "todo" entry (file "~/org/inbox.org")
     "* TODO %i%? \n:LOGBOOK: \n:CREATED: %U \n:END:")))
```

Comment: That's true.  Of course it would only work for creating TODOs from the capture template (and I have about a dozen of those that I'd have to update).  I'm really trying to intercept the function call.  Thanks for the idea, though.

Comment: Yes, I misread your question and will update the answer to reflect the fact that it is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method which writes a LOGBOOK into the org file line-by-line, below the current line, which is supposed to be a newly-created heading, and includes a CREATED: timestamp in the LOGBOOK. It does hard indenting using org-cycle, because I still do that.

```
(defun my/insert-logbook-created-timestamp (&rest ignore)
  "Insert a LOGBOOK drawer containing a 'CREATED:' timestamp."
  (save-excursion
    ; use org-cycle to hard-indent the lines
    (newline) (org-cycle) (insert ":LOGBOOK:\n")
    (org-cycle) (insert "CREATED: ")
    (org-insert-time-stamp nil t t nil "\n" nil)
    (org-cycle) (insert ":END:")
    ; fold the LOGBOOK
    (forward-line -2) (org-cycle)))
```

FWIW, without indenting, the LOGBOOK writing itself can be done with a single command:

```
(org-insert-time-stamp nil t t ":LOGBOOK:\nCREATED: " "\n:END:" nil)
```

The function can be added to the desired heading insertion function, for example:

```
(add-hook 'org-insert-heading-hook 'my/insert-logbook-created-timestamp 'append)
```

or:

```
(advice-add 'org-insert-todo-heading :after #'my/insert-logbook-created-timestamp)
```

References: [Bernt Hansen's bh/insert-heading-inactive-timestamp function](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#InsertInactiveTimestamps), [@andrej](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/46474/39877) in this thread, [@ebpa](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35776/39877) in another thread.

For capturing, it seems the function can be added to org-capture-before-finalize-hook, see [@miguelmorin](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/45369/39877) in that other thread, but I haven't tested it.